# Web2Py Production - making redirections on default index with parameters (maybe with nginx)

Tags: python, redirect, nginx, web2py

I am trying to create redirects using web2py from effectively the default index page (or just the route of the domain/package).
Some keywords (such as 'about', stored in a list) wouldn't redirect. However, all not in that list would redirect.

The desired behaviour is:

```
https://startbean.com/about -> No redirect
https://startbean.com/myc -> https://startbean.com/company/myc
```

The default page that is shown at startbean.com is from the package 'default' and is called 'index'. If the redirect was as in the below, it would be easy:

```
https://startbean.com/default/about -> No redirect
https://startbean.com/default/index/myc -> https://startbean.com/default/company/myc
```

because the `myc` is a URL argument. But when it is from the root, Web2Py tries to open a package called 'myc' and then finds no page (index or controller function) so errors.

What is the best way of handling this? I was trying with routes.py, but couldn't figure out a way to do this (am pretty sure it is not supported). I thought about a redirect for the token after `/` to a page called `/default/redirect/<token>` which would then decide about the redirect, but there's no way to stop the infinite loop. Another possible solution was a tweak to the nginx config so redirect when there is one token after the `/`, but again I think this causes a problem with the `about`.

Maybe there is a catch-all function for controllers that I haven't found? I've gone through the web2py book and found nothing - any ideas very welcome!

Thanks,

Sam

Comment: In https://startbean.com/company/myc, is company the controller and myc the function, or is the full web2py URL really /default/company/myc (i.e., company is the function and myc is a URL arg), and you would like to remove the /default/company part?

Comment: @Anthony the latter. I should have written myc as <token> or <arg> - the full application URL is `/default/company/myc` and `myc` is a URL arg. Removing the `/default/company` bit could be a cool bonus - but to be honest the main thing is to make the page visit-able from entering the URL without the `/default/company` part into the URL bar (so someone can share the URL: startbean.com/myc and get taken to the page startbean.com/company/myc). Any ideas?

Comment: web2py includes two different URL rewrite systems. The simpler parameter-based system allows you to specify a default application, controller, and function (within each controller). If "company" is the only function in the default controller that you want to hide, you could take this approach. If that would be suitable, I can detail the solution. Alternatively, you can create any arbitrary rewrite rules you want using the more complex pattern based system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the solution (sorry for the delay in posting):

In the `routes.py` at the route of web2py directory, I added a rule in routes_in, so that this was in the my file:

```
routes_in = (
  ('/(?!about)$token', '/company/$token'),
)
```

to manage the default app (removing the application name and the default package name from the URL), I did this (not necessary for the redirects to work):

```
routers = dict(
  BASE  = dict(default_application='startbean'),
)
```

And it all worked :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [parameter-based rewrite system](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/04/the-core#Parameter-based-system). In routes.py include:

```
routers = dict(
    BASE=dict(
        default_application='yourapp',
        default_controller='default',
        default_function='company',
        functions=['index', 'company', 'user', 'download', 'call']
    ),
)
```

Note, `functions` should be a list of all functions in the default.py controller.

If you go to /some_token, it will route to /yourapp/default/company/some_token, unless some_token is "yourapp", "default", "company", or any of the functions in the `functions` list (in which case, it will assume you are actually requesting the "yourapp" app, the "default" controller, or the particular function from the controller).

Note, if you simply go to the root URL (i.e., http://yourdomain.com/), it will route to /yourapp/default/company/, with no URL arg, so you should be prepared for that case.